# What are the similarities between jQuery and Prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

What are the similarities between jQuery and Prototype?

For example, they both have selectors, although Prototype's general selector uses $$. They both also have the .hide method.  Is there a good list of the similarities?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out this blog post at Ajaxian?

http://ajaxian.com/archives/prototype-and-jquery-a-code-comparison

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking for similarities but its easier to answer what the differences are (from a users point of view they aren't massively different)

[Migration Tutorial](http://andykdocs.de/andykdocs/document/Migrating-from-the-Prototype-JavaScript-Framework-to-jQuery)

[Migration Cheat Sheet](http://andykdocs.de/andykdocs/document/Migrating-from-the-Prototype-JavaScript-Framework-to-jQuery/Prototype-JS-to-jQuery-Migration-Cheat-Sheet-V1-April-2010.html) - That list you were looking for.

[What are the current differences between jQuery and Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064320/what-are-the-current-differences-between-jquery-and-prototype)

> **Prototype** is a mature framework that does a very good job shoring
>   up browser differences and providing very well-rounded functionality.
>   Unfortunately it is a bit heavy-handed with its changes to the default
>   Javascript environment, and it's not seeing rapid development and
>   doesn't have a significant plugin ecosystem.
>
> **jQuery** is a newer framework that was able to leverage some of the
>   lessons of the early javascript frameworks like Prototype to create
>   something more modular, less obtrusive, and significantly more
>   powerful and concise. I still love Prototype, but jQuery's DOM
>   manipulation and plugin ecosystem is just too good to ignore anymore.
>   If I was starting a greenfield project I'd have to go with jQuery
>   because that seems to be where the innovation is happening (at least
>   between those two choices).

Comment: JQuery is mature too... maybe 4 years ago it was "new", but it's definitely mature now.

Comment: definitely. It is still newer of the two and brings with it a new way of thinking.